# What does '{ it }' mean when assigned to a parameter?

Tags: kotlin, lambda

For example, it is being assigned in the parameter when calling this function this way

```
fun executeRequestWithoutSerializer (
      request : Request, 
      maxAttempts : Int? = 1
): Response {
     val result = executeRequest(
                request = request
                maxAttempts = maxAttempts,
                deserializer = { it }
        )

     return result
}
```

executeRequest takes in these parameters:

```
suspend fun <T: Any> executeRequest(
    request: Request,
    maxAttempts: Int = 2,
    deserializer: (Response) -> T
)
```

Comment: Do you understand what `it` means in general?

Comment: What does the argument type of `deserializer` mean? In words?

Comment: @Sweeper I have a broad idea, but every explaination is incredibly vague. It's a placeholder for a parameter. What I don't understand is what it means in this scenario and what does it do wrapped in the squiggly brackets '{ }'

Comment: @dawghaus `it` is really a very simple concept. If you create a lambda that receives exactly one parameter and you don't need to give this parameter any specific name, then by default it is named `it`. For example, if you have a list of numbers and you need to double each of them, you can write: `list.map { num -> num * 2 }`, but instead you can just do: `list.map { it * 2 }` - this is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `deserializer` parameter of the `executeRequest` function takes a lambda (a function). The lambda has a signature which is similar to a function like `fun <T:Any> deserializer(response: Response): T`

When you write `{ it }`, you are creating a function which returns `it`. `it` over here is the `Response` object that the `executeRequest` function will probably provide in its body and use that object to call the `deserializer` lambda.. And your lambda simply returns that `Response` object.

You can read more here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html